# Hive INFO logs are not getting suppressed in Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, logging, hive

There are two approaches to control logging. One is via log4j.properties and another via controlling it programmatically. I have tried both:
Via log4j.properties file:

```
# disable logging for spark libraries
log4j.additivity.org=false
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
#log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, NOAPPENDER
log4j.logger.org=ERROR, NOAPPENDER
```

and via programmatically:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(pkgName);
logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

I was able to suppress other logs but there are few INFO logs which are still getting printed:

```
INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
INFO Hive: Registering function addfunc ca.nextpathway.hive.UDFToDate
```

and

```
INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@17f9344b{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
```

I want to suppress all the INFO logs except for few specific packages. But I think I am nowhere near it. If anyone knows what could be the problem here please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below. This should work.

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hadoop.hive").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Comment: I have tried setting ERROR level for below packages but still getting the same logs:

    org.apache.hadoop.hive,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metadata

Answer (score 0):

The code
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/Hive.java has a bug. It creates the LOg as below:

```
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("hive.ql.metadata.Hive");
```

So the regular filter with org.apache.hadoop.hive does not work. Instead, you have to use "hive.ql.metadata.Hive". For example:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("hive.ql.metadata.Hive").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```